# What happens when using "class_weight" and "c" parameters simultaneously in svm.scv()?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to build a classifier. In playing around with hyperparameters, I happened to use the parameters `class_weights` and `C` simultaneously and am seeing results that I don't understand.

This code gives me a different f1 score

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel="linear",class_weight={1:10,0:5})
clf.fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
predicted=clf.predict(X_test_tfidf)
f1_score(y_test, predicted)
```

From this code

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel="linear",class_weight={1:10,0:5},c=5)
clf.fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
predicted=clf.predict(X_test_tfidf)
f1_score(y_test, predicted)
```

My understanding is that when setting class weights, you are setting `C` values per this equation [image: formula].

In that case, I would expect the `C` parameter to be ignored. But it doesn't seem to be. What is sklearn doing with it? Am I understanding something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting class weights and setting the `C` parameter are two independent things, and you should not expect the results to be the same.

The documentation says the following thing:

> In problems where it is desired to give more importance to certain classes or certain individual samples keywords class_weight and sample_weight can be used.
>
> SVC implement a keyword class_weight in the fit method. It’s a dictionary of the form {class_label : value}, where value is a floating point number > 0 that sets the parameter C of class class_label to C * value.

In other words:

- in your first example, you will have `C = 1*5 = 5` for class 0 and `C = 1*10 = 10` for class 1 (because the default value is 1.0)
- in your second example, you will have `C = 5*5 = 25` for class 0 and `C = 5*10 = 50` for class 1

Comment: I ran some tests with that information and can confirm that is what I'm seeing. Thank you! I didn't know it would multiply C by the class_weights.